# Is there a way to embed an external video player in Instagram?

Tags: html, html5-video, instagram

What I'd like to achieve is to be able to embed my own html5 video player maybe as an iframe or some other way on Instagram. So that I am able to post videos which will play within Instagram. Is that something that's possible. And if Yes, how do I go about doing that?